# Firebase Crashlogs leads me astray (iOS crash log)

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics, dispatch

I have a bug in my app which I am not able to reproduce on my own device and the firebase crash log doesn't really help me. Or maybe I am not able to understand it correctly. What is really weird is that it tells me lines of code where the crash happens which is in the millions.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
```

0  Flax                           0x102359394 CategoriesViewController.loadPosts(more:) + 4338652052 (CategoriesViewController.swift:4338652052)

1  Flax                           0x1023598d0 closure #1 in CategoriesViewController.loadPosts(more:) + 361 (CategoriesViewController.swift:361)

2  Flax                           0x102332c7c closure #5 in closure #1 in PostsAPI.loadPostsOrdered(start:order:limit:category:controller:onSuccess:) + 342 (PostAPI.swift:342)

3  Flax                           0x1022f9240 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4338258496 (:4338258496)

4  libdispatch.dylib              0x186e5ca84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32

5  libdispatch.dylib              0x186e5e81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20

6  libdispatch.dylib              0x186e6cc70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 884

7  CoreFoundation                 0x1871eb398 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 16

8  CoreFoundation                 0x1871e5270 __CFRunLoopRun + 2524

9  CoreFoundation                 0x1871e4360 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600

10 GraphicsServices               0x19e822734 GSEventRunModal + 164

11 UIKitCore                      0x189c5f584 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072

12 UIKitCore                      0x189c64df4 UIApplicationMain + 168

13 Flax                           0x1022b2e44 main + 21 (HashtagTableViewCell.swift:21)

14 libdyld.dylib                  0x186ea0cf8 start + 4

The crash happens rarely. The two lines which make sense (361 (CategoriesViewController.swift:361) and PostsAPI.loadPostsOrdered(start:order:limit:category:controller:onSuccess:) + 342 (PostAPI.swift:342) are actually empty lines which makes it even more confusing.

Like I said those functions are called thousands of times a day and crash maybe every 1000th time.

Any idea how to understand this crash log?

edit: The HashtagTableviewCell

```
import Foundation
import KILabel

class HashtagTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var hashtagCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HashTagLabel: UILabel!
    
    var hashtag: Hashtag!
    
    func updateView(hashtag:Hashtag) {
        self.hashtag = hashtag
        HashTagLabel.text = hashtag.mentions != -100 ? "# \(hashtag.tag!)" : "\(hashtag.tag!)"
        HashTagLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        hashtagCounter.text = hashtag.mentions == 1 ? "\(hashtag.mentions ?? 0) \(NSLocalizedString("HASHTAG_CELL_POSTS_1", comment: ""))" : "\(hashtag.mentions ?? 0) \(NSLocalizedString("HASHTAG_CELL_POSTS", comment: ""))"
        if hashtag.mentions == -100 {
            hashtagCounter.text = ""
        }
    }
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        HashTagLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        HashTagLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What is in those two lines?

Comment: those lines are actually empty in my code. Just blank lines.

Comment: A question which may be unrelated. Are you attempting to load Firebase data from within a TableViewCell?

Comment: No I am not. I load the post in my PostApi and then populate the cell with the fetched data. Interestingly it always shows the "hashtagtableviewcell" as a path of the crash. But its not used at all in this context. I talked to a user who encountered the crash and he said it just happens randomly but he doesn't use any of those views.

Comment: Hmm. If `HashtagTableViewCell` is never used at all then it should not be in the crash log. It could be unrelated but that's suspicious. I would open your project and Shift-Command-F (find in project) for `HashtagTableViewCell` and review every occurrence of that both in code and the UI Inspector. Also, this is a main thread crash which points to more of a UI element issue. Firebase networking calls are always called on a background thread so I would guess it's unrelated to Firebase. Investigating UI stuff is where I would start. Oh - and when replying use the at symbol - like @Jay

Comment: @Jay Yes I already looked through the Cell as it is weird that it shows up in the crash log. I will share the code of the cell above.

Comment: This is going to be hard to track down without really digging into it but this kind of thing `hashtag.tag!` is always a warning flag (to me). If for some reason `hashtag.tag` is nil then your code could mysteriously crash. So in general it's best to not force-unwrap optionals - they should be handled as if they *could* be nil (which, it could be which is why it's an optional). Safely unwrap that and if it's nil handle it accordingly by providing a default value or some other error handling.